# How to implement sift algorithm in 3 dimension using opencv and c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, sift

I am confused about how to implement sift algorithm in 3-dimension using opencv and c++. I understand the 3D sift algorithm principle from some papers but I don't have a clear mind on implementation. There are some open source code which is written in matlab, **I want to implement the algorithm using c++ and opencv but have no idea on delcaring the data structure**.

3D sift algorithm can be simply described as following steps:

**(1) Build the scale space and generate the DOG(Difference of Gaussian).**

(2) Detect the extrema and filter some inappropriate keypoints.

(3) Assign the keypoints orientation in 3D.

(4) Generate the keypoint descriptor in 3D.

Assume that the 3D input data is ready and can be stored in a 3D array(e.g. double*** data).

My first try is to declare the 3D matrix(3D Volume) by the following (the data in 3D array can be copied to the Mat):

```
int sizes[] = {x ,y, z};
Mat *Img = new Mat(3, sizes, CV_8U, Scalar(0));// using namespace cv
```

Then I encounter some problems in **step1** of the algorithm:

(1) Is there a way to **declare a 3D volume** using something like **typedef**, since the scale space contains different sizes of the 3D volume. The size array should not be constant.

(2) I cannot find ways to **resize the 3D volume or do the Gaussian filter for 3D volume**. Is it a reasonable approach to decompose the 3D volume into 2D slices and do the resize or Gaussian filter on each slices? Or is there any function can be directly applied on 3D volume?

Constructing the appropriate data structure should be the key of the algorithm and I don't have a clear mind on how to use opencv.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think you are using the wrong library for that purpose. Try one that is specialized in pointclouds and volumes like PCL, they even have a [version of SIFT](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_s_i_f_t_keypoint.html) which you can take a look at. Most of the filters and functions in OpenCV are thought for a 2D image. You can find some for 3D pointclouds, but you will have to implement a lot by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @api55. I will take a look at the PCL library. Since my experiment data is experimental material 3D data, I wonder whether the ITK and VTK libraries are appropriate or not since ITK and VTK specialize in the medical image processing. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> (1) Is there a way to declare a 3D volume using something like typedef, since the scale space contains different sizes of the 3D volume. The size array should not be constant.

No, OpenCV is primarily aimed at 2D Images (think standard image formats such as .png, video feeds etc)

> (2) I cannot find ways to resize the 3D volume or do the Gaussian filter for 3D volume. Is it a reasonable approach to decompose the 3D volume into 2D slices and do the resize or Gaussian filter on each slices? Or is there any function can be directly applied on 3D volume?

The only thing you can really do with OpenCV is have a stack of 2D sizes, all of a different size if you wanted. If you have a vector or sometype with a set of Mats then you could alter those mats to fit your purpose (you could even change the size of particular mats)

That being said it really sounds like what you are trying to do is probably out of the scope of OpenCV. For reference you can see OpenCVs implementation of SIFT [here](https://gist.github.com/lxc-xx/7088609)

Comment: Thanks, OpenCV seems to be not appropriate for my purpose. Maybe I need to implement by myself.